How to create an alternate version of the \subsection command that clears one page instead of two and uses a different syle for the page?
I'm trying to define an alternate version of the \subsection command, but this error keeps preventing me from compiling.
I'm using TexStudio with a LuaLatex compiler.
This is the command's syntax:
\WithSuffix\renewcommand\subsection*[1]{
    % Always on left page
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{LancerFancyNoHead}
    %\subsecbox{#1}
}

I've tried this solution but the \cleardoublepage seems to always activate:
\documentclass[twoside,headings,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\title{Your Title Here}
\author{Your Name Here}

% Command for making a sub-section box across top of page
\newcommand{\subsecbox}[1]{
    % Increment and reset counters
    \addtocounter{subsection}{1}
    \setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
    % Set header and footer iformation
    \renewcommand{\leftmark}{\partialleftmark  \slash{}\slash{} #1}
    \renewcommand{\rightmark}{#1}
    % Create "physical" anchor for links and add line to table of contents
    \phantomsection\etoctoccontentsline*{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}{1}
    % Create named anchor for links.
    \label{#1}
    % Add actual title box
    \begin{figure*}[t!]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red,size=small, arc is angular, sharp corners, rounded corners=southeast,
                arc=1.1\baselineskip, boxrule=0pt, hbox, grow to left by=1in, left*=0pt, top=1mm, bottom=1mm, scale=2.5, move upwards=-0.5in,varwidth upper=\textwidth]
            \noindent
            \raggedright
            \fontsize{36}{60}
            \textbf{\textcolor{white}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
            \hspace{0.55\baselineskip}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{figure*}
    \justifying\normalsize
}

% ReDefine \subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
    % Always on left page
    %\cleardoublepage
    \subsecbox{#1}
}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexsubsection}{\subsection}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{t+}{%
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{\clearpage\thispagestyle{LancerFancyNoHead}}%
    \else{\cleardoublepage}\fi
    \latexsubsection
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\subsection{aaa}
\subsection{bbb}
\subsection+{ccc}
\subsection+{ddd}
\subsection{eee}
\subsection{fff}

\end{document}

[SOLVED].
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
    % Always on left page
    %\cleardoublepage
    \subsecbox{#1}
}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexsubsection}{\subsection}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{t+}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\clearpage\thispagestyle{LancerFancyNoHead}}{\cleardoublepage}
    \latexsubsection
}


The * is not a part of the macro name, so this will never work. Plus a standard \subsection has three "arguments", an optional *, optional title in []'s and the mandatory argument. Might be better to start over an explain what exactly you end goal is and then people can help with a solution.

I'm using a template made by someone else. The documentation they left said the \subsection* command was for starting sections without them having to start always on the right page

So what would be a better way to have two different versions of the \subsection command?

You didn't add a specification of what you want, just wrong code…

Anyway, I guess you want \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\clearpage}{\cleardoublepage}

Sorry and thanks for the clarification on the syntax: now it behaves like it is supposed to.

Please don't edit solutions into your question. That's very confusing.

What is the correct way of showcasing a solution I arrived at myself then? (Even though it is just a slight modification of a solution provided in the answers)

As usual with David Kastrup's packages, the documentation is not what is generally considered helpful.
If your aim is to change \subsection so that the *-variant issues \clearpage and chooses a particular page style, you can do in the following way.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % small pictures

\NewCommandCopy{\latexsubsection}{\subsection}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\clearpage\thispagestyle{plain}}%
  \latexsubsection
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\section{Test section}

\subsection{xyz}

No new page

\subsection*{yyy}

New page

\end{document}


But I'd avoid changing this way the meaning of a basic command. Why not a + instead?
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % small pictures

\NewCommandCopy{\latexsubsection}{\subsection}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{t+}{%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\clearpage\thispagestyle{plain}}%
  \latexsubsection
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\section{Test section}

\subsection{xyz}

No new page

\subsection+{yyy}

New page

\end{document}


This is almost what I need.
In truth I need to use the same page style regardless: the only thing that changes is whether the command starts with \cleardoublepage (without the +) or with \clear page (with the +)

Ok sorry I had misapplied your solution. Now I've written it like this:
% ReDefine \subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
% Always on left page
%\cleardoublepage
\subsecbox{#1}
}
%\WithSuffix\renewcommand\subsection*[1]{
%    % Always on left page
%    \clearpage
%    \thispagestyle{LancerFancyNoHead}
%    \subsecbox{#1}
%}
\NewCommandCopy{\latexsubsection}{\subsection}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{t+}{%
\IfBooleanT{#1} \clearpage\thispagestyle{LancerFancyNoHead}%
\else \cleardoublepage
\fi
\latexsubsection
}

It almost works but both versions still do \cleardoublepage

@LucaBallanzeddu Long snippets of code in comments are unreadable. Please, add a complete specification to your question.

Edited my question: what do you think?
